# Is it possible to run OpenStack on a laptop/desktop?

Tags: openstack

I have some questions:

1. Is it possible to install openstack on a Notebook with a 4GB DD3 Ram? Because the website says it needs atleast 8GB of RAM.
2. They say it requirs a double-QuadCore , I assue that means Octacore.  Can we install that on a Quadcore?
3. They say that there is no possibility to install it on a NAS . Did you find any where if there is a possibility to do?. I dint find any even after asking our friend(google).
4. All in all, is it at-all possible to install on it a notebook/Desktop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That advice is for production environments,

so 1)If you just want to play around your notebook will do fine. I had a succesful test-run on a 1.2 Ghz 1GB Netbook. It became incredibly slow when it launched it's first instance... 
With a Double Quadcore they actually mean two seperate Quad-cores, as in two quad-core xeon processors on a single motherboard

So 2) yes you can install it on a quad-core.

3) a NAS device running openstack an openstack storage service seems to be unlikely indeed. You will most likely need more computing power.However If your NAS supports NFS or SSH or sth you can probably mount this drive and use it for storage.

4) You can perfectly build a all-in-one openstack test setup on your notebook. Performance will be low, but acceptable for testing.

Comment: Thanks. That clarified a lot for me. 

Just one more question : I was trying to give authentication, access permissions and was trying edit the proxy-server.conf file. is it that the file is available after installing openstack or is there something that I am missing.

[link](https://github.com/gholt/swauth)

Comment: Do you recommend me to start off with UbuntuCloudInfrastructure which is based on OpenStack - [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure)

Comment: When installing swift you need to create a lot of configuration files yourself, so no, it is not missing =)

Secondly, our private cloud is also completely based on Ubuntu nodes, but we didn't use MAAS/JuJu for deployment. we used the [Hastexo](http://www.hastexo.com/resources/docs/installing-openstack-essex-20121-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin) guide initially but then used the OpenStack documentation to complete our cloud since hastexo doesn't really clarify what is exactly needed per service (per node)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "install OpenStack". OpenStack itself is an extremely modular framework consisting on many services (Compute, Networking, Image service, Block Storage, Object Storage, Orchestration, Telemetry, ...). On top of that, a typical production deployment of OpenStack also requires several components, like load balancers, caching systems, firewalls, web servers and others. It is definitely possible to install a minimal openstack system, even on an average laptop.

The simplest way to run OpenStack on a laptop/desktop is to [use Devstack](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/), a shell script that installs all services from source and run them (by default) on a single machine. It is customizable enough to provide very good testing ground; it's used by OpenStack developers as well as the OpenStack QA team to test latest developments against "real" systems.

To avoid messing up your system, it's generally recommended to install OpenStack in a VM. From devstack doc:

> DevStack should run in any virtual machine running a supported Linux release. It will perform best with 2Gb or more of RAM.

As of the time of this writing (Jan 2015), supported distros are:

- Ubuntu (latest LTS)
- Fedora
- CentOS

Answer (score 0):

Regarding NAS: you can of course use it, but "outside" Openstack apis, by providing mount points to your vms. It's even mandatory if you want to support live migration.